# php/mysql - Compare multiple columns from 2 tables and show biggest differnce

Tags: php, mysql, compare, difference

I have 1 main table with all my info and 1 table with almost the same structure but slightly different values. Now i want to compare these values and get de highest difference back. I got this working with a query for each column (a1-a5) and in the loop of each query i query again and do some calculations with the results...i dunno, it's messy and i'm not sure how to get this in a clean way.

This is the structure of the 2 tables:

```
+----------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
| HomeTeam | AwayTeam | Result |  a1 |  a2 |  a3 |  a4 |  a5 |  Date        |
+----------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
| team1    | team2    |      H |  5  |  2  |  4  |  4  |  3  |  11-04-2017  |
| team3    | team4    |      A |  6  |  8  |  4  |  2  |  6  |  11-04-2017  |
| team1    | team3    |      D |  3  |  7  |  9  |  7  |  2  |  12-04-2017  |
| team4    | team2    |      H |  2  |  4  |  8  |  6  |  5  |  12-04-2017  |
+----------+----------+--------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--------------+

+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| HomeTeam | AwayTeam |  a1 |  a2 |  a3 |  a4 |  a5 |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| team1    | team2    |  2  |  3  |  5  |  3  |  3  |
| team3    | team4    |  5  |  7  |  5  |  2  |  3  |
| team1    | team3    |  4  |  2  |  8  |  6  |  5  |
| team4    | team2    |  2  |  5  |  5  |  6  |  4  |
+----------+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

And this is what i want to print:

```
team 1 vs team 2 biggest increase was 150% (a1 -> 5 vs 2) on 11-04-2017 
team 3 vs team 4 biggest increase was 100% (a5 -> 6 vs 3) on 11-04-2017 
team 1 vs team 3 biggest increase was 250% (a2 -> 7 vs 2) on 12-04-2017 
team 4 vs team 2 biggest increase was 60% (a3 -> 8 vs 5) on 12-04-2017
```

While i'm typing this i'm thinking to maybe just use one query to get everything from both tables and use the values to do some calculations? Not sure..someone who can give me a big kick in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Please update the question with your current code also. It can be solved in MySQL level itself.

Comment: I have no idea what your data represents, but just by looking at the tables it seems to me that your tables are not normalized, making your queries unnecessarily complex. I suspect that the numbers in a1...a5 represent the same type of data, and should be in just one column. An extra column could be used for the 1...5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `GREATEST` here to find the largest spread for each match:

```
SELECT
    HomeTeam,
    AwayTeam,
    GREATEST(t1.a1 - t2.a1, t1.a2 - t2.a2, t1.a3 - t2.a3, t1.a4 - t2.a4, t1.a5 - t2.a5) AS max_diff
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.HomeTeam = t2.HomeTeam AND t1.AwayTeam = t2.AwayTeam;
```

If you want the actual `a` values as well, then it would be a lot more work, especially given that your data is not normalized.  You might want to normalize your data for anything more complicated than the above.